# Is "tomfoolery" a gendered word?

Tags: gender-neutral, political-correctness

I saw a comment of someone referring to *tom-and-tanya-foolery* as the gender-inclusive version of *tomfoolery*. I was completely unaware of *tomfoolery* having any gendered connotation at all.

Is this a common term, and does the word *tomfoolery* have a gendered origin?

Comment: That’s nutzoid.  *Tomfoolery* does not suffer from gender bias. --tom

Comment: What @tchrist said. Apparently not a single person has ever been minded to use the obvious "feminised" alternative **tibfoolery** in Google Books *or* the Internet at large. Case dismissed.

Comment:  .

Comment: Why is this being voted to close? This is a term someone used and I wanted to know if Tomfoolery had any historical contexted as a gendered term. Given the push towards gender-neutral terms in English (which I support) a definative answer would have been nice.

Comment: Why assume that "Tom" refers to someone male? Talk about gender bias! ;-)

Comment: If discussing cats or turkeys, yes.

Comment: @drew - perhaps the 'fool' is the part that is exclusively male.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Tomfoolery**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tomfoolery?s=t) in modern English has no sense of gender beyond the name Tom being present in the word.  It is a combination of [**tomfool + -ery**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tomfool)

That said, it derives from Middle English *Thome Fole*:  Tom the Fool.

From the Online Etymological Dictionary:  Tomfool - "buffoon, clown," 1650, from M.E. Thom Foole, personification of a mentally deficient man (1338), see Tom + fool. Tomfoolery is recorded from 1812.  (*Sorry, the link on etymonline.com seems to be broken, I found this at the bottom of the Dictionary.com entry*)

So, at some point it *did* refer to a man.

Personally, I think it is perfectly appropriate to refer to the actions of either men or women as tomfoolery.*

---

<sup>***Note:**  You may find people who insist on gender scrubbing or equality in terms like this, but my advice is to stop speaking to these people immediately.  You will just be happier.  Take my word for it....</sup>

Comment: I think the term should be banned because it exhibits prejudice against fools.